# display windows server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis-7.5

I have a display problem and i have no idea where the problem can be.

i'll explain:

The application that is working right now look like this:
[Working display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7bfR.jpg)

It is running on windows 7.

The same application running on Windows server 2008 R2 look like this:
[not working display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skq5p.jpg)

I use the same IIS version on both servers : 7.5.
Framework .Net used is version 3.5.
The browser is also not the problem.

Do you have already seen a problem like this?
Do you have any leads on what can change the display?

Thank you for your helps,

Comment: You should add more information. Why do you think the browser is not the problem? Did you try an other one and looked at the Developer Tools (F12 option)?

Answer (score 0):

From the picture you provided, looks like you are using IE to access the site. In windows 2k8 R2, many IE settings are disable for security reason. So maybe you can try chrome, or enable those settings. For example: 
Internet Options -> Security -> Custom Level